# Symfony 2.0: How to validate embedded collection of forms without an entity

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

How can I validate embedded collection of forms (without entities) in Symfony 2.0? Upgrading to 2.1 isn't a convenient option at the moment if the solution lies along that line.

I've tried using the `Valid` constraint and it caused all validations to fail instead.

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array (
        ...

        // I tried Valid constraint but this "removes" all validation
        'travel_links' => new Valid(),
    ));

    return array ('validation_constraint' => $collectionConstraint);
}
```

Comment: Something like this should do it: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms.html#adding-validation

Comment: Hi @cheesemacfly, I updated the question, I meant a *collection* of forms. The link you gave is for simple fields not embedded forms, I believe.

Comment: You're right! I probably read your question too fast...

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony 2.1, you could use the **constraints** option:

```
$builder
->add('firstName', 'text', array(
   'constraints' => new Length(array('min' => 3)),
))
->add('lastName', 'text', array(
   'constraints' => array(
       new NotBlank(),
       new Length(array('min' => 3)),
),
));
```

Obviously, that **does not** work in Symfony 2.0; however, a limited constraints option called **validation_constraint** is available in Symfony 2.0.

```
$builder
->add('firstName', 'text', array(
   'validation_constraint' => new Length(array('min' => 3)),
));
```

If you need to validate multiple conditions (e.g. NotBlank, Lenght) you can help yourself, defining a **[Custom constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html)** that does all validation at once. :)

Edit: Don't forget to include `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length` or whatever Constraint you are using. :)

Answer (score 0):

In actual version of Symfony2.x you can set cascade_validation to true (by default it's false)
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html

The documentation says : "Set this option to true to force validation on embedded form types. For example, if you have a ProductType with an embedded CategoryType, setting cascade_validation to true on ProductType will cause the data from CategoryType to also be validated.

Instead of using this option, you can also use the Valid constraint in your model to force validation on a child object stored on a property."